# Matching ContentID to the resource name or title on Facebook Analytics

Tags: facebook, facebook-analytics

While reading Facebook Analytic's [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events/android), I stumbled upon this default event called `EVENT_NAME_VIEWED_CONTENT` that accepts 3 params: `CONTENT_TYPE, CONTENT_ID and CURRENCY`.

I'm wondering if Facebook provide a way match the `CONTENT_ID` and `CONTENT_TYPE` to get the resource's **name** maybe through a standardized endpoint that my backend should be implementing or something.

**Disclaimer**: I know I could just make a custom event that would also receive the `name` or `title` parameter, but I'm interested in using the defaults for now.

Answer (score 1):

There's currently no way to configure Facebook Analytics to do this lookup through your own backend. However, you can use custom parameters with predefined events:

```
FB.AppEvents.logEvent(
  FB.AppEvents.EventNames.VIEWED_CONTENT,
  null /* valueToSum */,
  {
    [FB.AppEvents.ParameterNames.CONTENT_ID]: contentId,
    name: contentName,
  },
);
```

There's also nothing stopping you from passing a string to `CONTENT_ID` if you're really only interested in the resource's name.

```
FB.AppEvents.logEvent(
  FB.AppEvents.EventNames.VIEWED_CONTENT,
  null /* valueToSum */,
  {
    [FB.AppEvents.ParameterNames.CONTENT_ID]: contentName,
  },
);
```